# How do I unzip/untar a file on a remote machine using ssh command?

Tags: linux, ssh

I've got a zipped file on server A, B, C. I want to unzip these from server Z.

The command `ssh -f ip "unzip path/file.zip"` is searching for the path on the server where I run the command and not on the specified IP. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works on my machine...

Comment: May be you should login to server Z and then ssh to A, B and C servers?

Comment: @init: the ssh is run on Z.

Comment: @user55325: could ypu post the command uv run?

Comment: I actually did `ssh -f ip "tar zxf file.tar.gz"` but I can't imagine that unzip would be any different.

Comment: I just checked, and unzip works just as well as tar. Could it be that a shell variable is getting expanded before the command is sent to the remote machine?

Comment: -1 this is a mixed up question.. You should ask A)How do you run a command with ssh autmatically B)How do you unzip a file on a linux or unix-like machine, regardless of ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`ssh user@A "unzip path/file.zip"`

If it is working, then add `-f` to put it in background:

`ssh -f user@A "unzip path/file.zip"`

`ssh -f user@B "unzip path/file.zip"`

`ssh -f user@C "unzip path/file.zip"`